# laravel prevent overload data on Auth::user()

Tags: laravel, authentication, relationship

My model User have some relation: profile, activites, etc...
on my controller i have this:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->load(['profile', 'activities']);
```

excpected result on my blade is that my variable $user is with my relationships and the Auth::user() data remain the users table data only;

i have a layout `layout.blade.php` and a view `index.blade.php` that extends my layout;

in my index i want to use the relation data and in my layout i want only the users data; but i always have the relation loaded from controller

Comment: Because you load the relations. But why not access the user values you need in layout and relations values in index?

Comment: The question is "why do you want to unload the relations", once it is loaded it's better to keep it there as you might need it and it will save you a DB query.

Answer (score 1):

If you load any relationship, laravel will add that relationship in your user object automatically.

If you don't want this and want the user only, you can duplicate the object first to another variable before loading any relation.

Second option, you can get the user again

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the same object but without the relationship you have multiple choices:

```
$user->unsetRelation('profile');//unset specific relationship on the $user Object
$user->unsetRelations();//unset all relationships on the $user Object
$userWithoutRelationships = $user->withoutRelations();//clone the current Object but without relationships
```